# Angularjs custom directive with custom validation: form.$valid delay

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I am using a custom directive in combination with a custom validator. The problem I have is that myForm.$valid is true for a short moment before being invalidated.

```
 <form name="myForm">
   <!--If min-size="2" is added here, you don't see the Valid flashed-->
   <!-- I guess this is because no directive is used? -->
   <div name="testlist1" ng-model="data.testlist1"></div>


   <div testlist name="testlist2" ng-model="data.testlist2" min-size="3"></div>


   <div ng-if="myForm.testlist2.$valid">
     This is not flashed!
   </div>
   <div ng-if="myForm.$valid">
     This is flashed for a short time when loading!
   </div>
</form>

**data.testlist1 and data.testlist2 ara both empty arrays
```

Full example here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/MLILBxtqzA1x0IoPBZQb?p=preview

Someone has an idea why this is happening? And how to solve this?

---

Edit:
I found this note on the angularjs website.

> Note that child elements that contain templateUrl directives will not have been compiled and linked since they are waiting for their template to load asynchronously and their own compilation and linking has been suspended until that occurs.

I guess this is the reason? But is there a way to fix it?